# How to secure web ui in spark embedded with spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-spark, spring-security

I have a spring boot microservices application, some services include spark (embedded). Actually, I secured all the application and I need to secure the access to Spark Web UI. I checked the spark doc and other resources and they say that I should implement a Filter but I don't know if this is the right way and for my case.

The main objective is to limit access to the ui interface. I already added authentication using Kerberos, ldap and jwt so i would like to use same process with spark and make access using ldap.

Any other suggestion are welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe having a look to apache knox to provide autentication and gateway to all UI of the Hdp ecosystem => https://knox.apache.org/

Comment: Can you describe how you added authentication to the UI? Did you use Spring Security? (I'm noticing the `spring-security` tag in your post)

Comment: no i used spring security to secure my services not for spark ui i would like to use spring if possible. right kow i use this code to add a basic authentification https://www.fortytools.com/blog/servlet-filter-for-http-basic-auth with static user and password